# CSS backgroudn transition, what's wrong here?

Tags: css

I feel cursed to never get the background color transition correct and it's making me feel inadequate...

It does not transition between the background colors, just "blips" from one to the next without any transition at all. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="flowItem">
    Test
</div>

.flowItem { 
    -webkit-transition: background 1000ms linear;
    -moz-transition: background 1000ms linear;
    -ms-transition: background 1000ms linear;
    -o-transition: background 1000ms linear;
    transition: background 1000ms linear;
}
.flowItem:hover {
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #E0FFFF, #87CEEB);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.00, #E0FFFF), color-stop(1.0, #87CEEB));
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/metalphoenix/45vdd8fL/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

background images can't be “transitioned” like other properties: what should be an intermediate value of a `background-image` during a transition?

As a workaround you could apply the background to a pseudoelement, with `position: absolute` and a negative `z-index`. Then you can show the pseudoelement by animating its `opacity` property, like so

https://jsfiddle.net/45vdd8fL/4/

```
.flowItem {
    position: relative;
}

.flowItem::before {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    transition: opacity 1s linear;

    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;   
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #E0FFFF, #87CEEB);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.00, #E0FFFF), color-stop(1.0, #87CEEB));

}

.flowItem:hover::before {
   opacity: 1; 
}
```

Comment: Note that some older browsers don’t support transitions on `::before` and `::after`.

Comment: really older browser (Chrome < 25)

Comment: Can't speak for the downvoter, but it's interesting to note that the spec says [gradients can be animated](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-types) - although so far, only IE has implemented this. I certainly would not have downvoted for this reason though.

Answer (score 1):

[`background-image` is not an animatable property.](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties)) You’ll need to find some other way; for example, an element with an `opacity` transition to act as the background.

```css
.flowItem {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}

.flowItem::before {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#E0FFFF, #87CEEB);
    bottom: 0;
    content: '';
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s linear;
    z-index: -1;
}

.flowItem:hover::before {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/45vdd8fL/6/)

Comment: which is the purpose of having changed your answer so as to be identical to mine?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan: I originally used `::before`, remembered the compatibility problem, then decided it wasn’t relevant for my answer.

Comment: @Fabrizio Calderan: It doesn't seem like a complete rewrite - the original answer was fairly similar anyway. Probably nothing to worry about.